# Problem redirecting to /public folder in a Laravel project on Apache

Tags: php, linux, laravel, apache, debian

I have the following situation with a Laravel project. I uploaded the project to a Linux Server in the /var/www/html/tup folder.

I can access the site with the link http://www.example.com/tup/public as shown in this image
[(First Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck9m7.png)

I want to access directly without entering the public in the URL i. e. http://www.example.com/tup

I tried with a .htaccess file in the main folder of the project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# That was ONLY to protect you from 500 errors
# if your server did not have mod_rewrite enabled

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# NOT needed unless you're using mod_alias to redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
# Direct all requests to /public folder

</IfModule>
```

But when I enter to http://www.example.com/tup Laravel throws a 404 Not Found error
[(404 error Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPfRI.png). I have to write http://www.example.com/tup/index.php for Laravel to redirect me like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUNY6.png).

It seems that the index.php file is not being detected

In the public folder a I have another .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I already modified the apache2.conf file and set all the AllowOverride to All and enabled mod_rewrite as well.

I also added this configuration in the apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/tup/public/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I would greatly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: have you restarted the server? `sudo systemctl apache2 restart`

Comment: Yes, I restarted it several times.

Comment: try with what I wrote in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable `mod_rewrite`:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and in the `000-default.conf` you should have something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/tup/public/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

this will redirect your website (visit `http://www.example.com`) to the laravel project

Comment: As I mentioned before the mod_rewrite was already enabled. I added those lines in the 000-default.conf and restarted the server but still nothing.

Comment: @FDarfe what url are you trying to hit? what DNS record is pointing to this webserver?

Answer (score 1):

add the following to 000-default.conf, you will then be able to access without any rewrite rules.

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tup/public

    
    <Directory /var/www/html/tup/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: This is the most minimum required to make it work. No need to fiddle around .htaccess